# prettyPhoto with dynamic content JQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

HELLO i have this code that is loading content via AJAX call, these are vimeo videos and working when i put static code... but not with dynamically loaded content i tried many solution but not working for me
any help would be appriciated
here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[data-rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
    $(".category").click(function(){
        var categoryid = $(this).data('categoryid');
            $.ajax({
                url:'<?php echo base_url() ?>main/getPortfolioVideos',
                type:'POST',
                data: { category_id: categoryid, page_slug: "index" }
                }).done(function(data){
                    var rows = $.parseJSON(data);
                    var videodata = "";
                    $(rows).each(function(index, value){
                            $.each(value, function(k, v){
                                if(k == "video_link"){
                                    videodata += '<article class="entry"> <a data-rel="prettyPhoto" href="http://vimeo.com/'+ v +'">';
                                    videodata += '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'+ v +'" width="270" height="160" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="">';
                                    videodata += '</iframe><span class="video-hover"></span> </a> </article>';  
                                }
                                console.log(k+":"+v);
                            });
                    })
                    $(".portfolio").html(videodata);
                });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late answer, I have today the same problem. So, I have fixed it in the following way - just added to the $.ajax success function code, which calls pretty photo if new content appears.

First, write a function-wrapper:

```
function prettyPhotoLoad()
{
     // apply prettyPhoto plugin for video previews
     $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();    
}
```

Apply pretty photo when document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{   
    prettyPhotoLoad();
}
```

Make ajax call and renew the pretty photo:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: base_url + "/ajax/ShowMoreWebResults",    
    success: function(myVal)
    {   
        $("#resultsContainer").append(myVal.content);

        // load pretty photo
        prettyPhotoLoad();
    }
});
```

Note: I have Resolved my issue by using the `"$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();"` line. Thanks for this answer.